# What does the third valve/sensor do on this washing machine inlet?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a ~15 years old Whirlpool washing machine (Duet Steam with front load, model #W10251899C), which recently started getting F20 errors (insufficient water supply).

Even when the machine doesn't throw the error, water level in the machine during the washing cycle seems to be very low. Water barely covers the bottom of the drum (one inch above the lowest part of the drum, or even less). It's an HE model which is supposed to reduce water consumption, but I've owned other HE machines, and they all used more water

I have cleaned up the inlet screens, which seemed to have helped with the errors. But I was also wondering if I could increase the water level in the machine.

I tried to adjust the pressure sensor, but I couldn't find it. The closest thing to it that I did find was this valve/sensor on the water inlet block:

[image]

The third valve in the middle is connected with a rubber pipe to the white PVC air duct on the left hand side. The duct opens to the atmosphere. I thought that it was the pressure sensor, but I don't see how it can work, given that it's connected with the atmosphere.

I don't understand the function of this third valve/sensor.

I couldn't find the exact valve block online, but this one looks very similar to it (#WPW10247305):

[image]

https://applianceparts365.com/whirlpool-water-valve-3-coil-washer-part-wpw10247305

(the first Google hit with a decent image, not affiliated).

What does the part marked as "mystery valve" on the picture do?

UPDATE, after some further investigation:

It seems to have the double function: this is indeed a **steam valve** and it is connected to the water pipeline by a tiny pipe inside the casing. I had to take the valve block off and look real closely to see it.

It seems to have the double function:

1. Fill the drum through the diffuser pipe, bypassing the drawer. I couldn't activate this function in any of the normal cycles, but one of the cycles in the self-test has it.
2. Let the steam out from the drum when the washing machine is full and the steam can't get through the water to the diffuser pipe.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this site works a bit differently than general discussion forums do. Your first two questions really make this too broad, as you're really (I think) asking about how to get your washer repaired. Your title question doesn't line up with that, either. The more theoretical "how does this work" and "what's this for" parts might be OK if you asked them as stand-alone questions, but they make this one too broad. Please [edit] your question to focus on the real, single thing you're interested in resolving, then ask others if you'd like.

Comment: I copied and pasted your valuable update into this question. Once you have  merged your accounts you will have author permissions for this question again.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities:

1. The output of multiple valves lead to the detergent basket/drawer.

Depending on your model there is allowance for hot water, and for several additional drawer compartments.

The cold inlet is led to pre-wash, softener, bleach and main wash (1..4 valves), and the hot inlet valve (5th valve) mixes in hot water into the flow as needed for the temperature.

2. It could also be a steam valve

It looks like they may have used a common 3-valve assembly and used the 3rd valve as a "Steam Valve" (SV). It would work as follows: with "Hot Valve" HV and "Cold Valve" CV closed, the controller can use SV to relieve steam/pressure from the drum housing back through the water hose.

I suspect the valve assembly interconnects the waterways and steam escapes via the blue water supply line, then the valve, and then green line.

The *repair manual* for your machine will detail the specific operation, the valve wiring, and the tubing.

[image]

[image]

Image: https://www.applianceblog.com, https://applianceassistant.com/Washer-Repair/Duet/Duet-Part-Testing.php

Comment: The third valve on my picture opens to the air duct. It's not connected with water.

Comment: @WashingMachineUser how many compartments does your drawer have? That may not be an air duct but just a dummy hose for an unused function and unused valve in your particular model.

Comment: three: bleach, softener and detergent. All the water goes in through a single rubber pipe marked with a blue highlight on the picture.

Comment: ok, it could be the steam valve

Comment: what does a steam valve do?

Comment: @WashingMachineUser to let steam in from a boiler to drum (unlikely in your scenario based on the hoses) or to let steam out to regulate pressure in the drum, in which case the white PVC assembly is a diffuser

Comment: but how does let anything in or out? there is just one rubber hose, coming straight from the white PVC duct and ending up in this device. There is nothing passing through it. I understand how this thing can be a sensor of some kind, but not a valve. Your schematics say "CV", "HV" and "5V", with "CV" and "HV" supposedly standing for "cold valve" and "hot valve", what could "5V" in this context mean?

Comment: maybe steam comes in the green hose and goes out the blue hose

Comment: @WashingMachineUser "5V" is "SV" Steam Valve. Looks like they used a common 3-valve assembly and the 3rd valve as SV: with HV and CV closed, the controller can use SV to relieve steam/pressure from the drum housing back through the water hose.

Comment: @P2000: I found a 3D picture of this part: https://tinyurl.com/2uxbap7n, and unless I'm missing something obvious, this valve is indeed the same as the hot and cold ones, but it's not controlling any flow. Its brown plug is connected to a rubber hose which opens straight to the PVC duct. During the rinse cycle, I can feel cold air coming out of this duct, at very little pressure. When you say "controller can use SV to relieve steam/pressure", how exactly does it work?

Comment: @WashingMachineUser I think at this point you should consider buying the repair manual for your machine. It will detail the specific operation, the valve wiring, and the tubing.

Comment: @P2000: I found it online (that's where the better picture is from), and it is indeed something called "steam valve". The question was "what does it do", and I still can't find the answer to that in the manual. Your comment about using the steam valve to relieve the pressure looks promising. What's baffling me is how the steam gets to the steam valve. It is connected to the rest of the assembly with a really thin plastic bridge which is maybe 5mm wide. Maybe there is indeed a little steam pipe hidden inside this bridge. I am going to take the machine apart and verify that.

Comment: @WashingMachineUser if you can link to the doc (at source a shared copy) I will also have a look. And yes I suspect the assembly does interconnect the waterways and steam escapes via the blue water supply line, then the valve, and then green line.